# Как установить oracle apex19.1 на oracle 10 g?

Tags: oracle-apex

Как установить oracle apex19.1 на oracle 10 g?

Comment: Скорее всего, никак, так как офф. документация требует минимум 11.2.

Answer (score 0):

Из документации:

> Oracle Database Requirements: *Oracle Application Express release 19.1 requires an Oracle Database release 11.2.0.4 or later, including Enterprise Edition and Express Edition (Oracle Database XE).*

Поэтому боюсь никак.

[Oracle Application Express Installation Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmig/Oracle-AE-installation-requirements.html#GUID-02BE4A34-B631-412C-8A82-EB92DABBACE0)